# form select size not working with DB populated options

Tags: html

I have a SELECT element in form with about 70 options. All the options are not seen in the browser, so I am trying to add size="10" so that I get a vertical scroll. But it is not working. The options are populated from mysql database.

```
<select size="10" name="depid">
                                   <?php
$wa_startindex = 0;
while(!$listdephosdepartment->atEnd()) {
  $wa_startindex = $listdephosdepartment->Index;
?>
                                       <option value="<?php echo($listdephosdepartment->getColumnVal("id")); ?>"><?php echo($listdephosdepartment->getColumnVal("name")); ?></option>
                                     <?php
  $listdephosdepartment->moveNext();
}
$listdephosdepartment->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
unset($wa_startindex);
unset($wa_repeatcount);
?>
 </select>
```

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It would be useful to see more of the HTML\css for this.

Comment: Hello Martin,You can view the html here [link](http://arjlifecare.ru/test.html)

Comment: @Martin I have posted the link to html

Answer (score 0):

The add size="10" didn't worked for me. So I changed CSS to at least make it scrollable and visible. Here is the CSS code

```
.scrollmenu {
   max-height:500px;
   overflow:scroll; 
}
```